# Can't move button to the furthest right of div while using flexbox

Tags: html, css

I'm having a little problem, I created a div and inside that div I'm displaying a text and a button, I'm using flexbox, I want the button's right side to touch the furthest point of the div, so there's no space between the end of the div and the button's end. However, when I try to position it using margins, the button shrinks and doesn't position itself in a way I want to, it just stays in the same position and reduces its size.
Here's the code  :

```
<div className='subscribe-background-div'>
     <h2>Email Address</h2>
     <Button  className="btn btn-light me-5 subscribe-btn">Subscribe</Button>
</div>
```

and the CSS :

```
.subscribe-background-div{
    width: 339px;
    height: 48px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    opacity: 1;
    border: 1px solid #FFFFFFD9;
    border-radius: 12px;
    opacity: 1;
    margin-top: 5%;
}

.subscribe-background-div h2{
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    color: #717179;
    opacity: 1;
    margin-top: 45px;
    margin-left: 20px;
   
}

.subscribe-btn{
    width: 126px;
    height: 48px;
}
```

Here's a picture of how it looks for now :

[image]

And I want it to look like this :

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try to change `justify-content` to `space-between`

Answer (score 1):

try to use this in your css,

```
.subscribe-btn{
width: 126px;
height: 48px;
margin-left:auto;
```

}

Comment: added the last line but it changed nothing

Answer (score 1):

there are 2 issue with your code
first if this is html and not jsx:

```
<div className='subscribe-background-div'>
```

should be

```
<div class='subscribe-background-div'>
```

and second this

```
.subscribe-background-div {
 justify-content: space-around;
}
```

probably has to be

```
.subscribe-background-div {
 justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Comment: With the way their code is written, they are probably using React. Also, space-between wouldn't fix their issue.

Comment: yea I'm using React, also, space-between didn't help

Answer (score 1):

You might want to remove the `justify-content: space-around;` in the parent.

Normally we will grow the `input` (or `h2` in your case) to push the `button` to the end of the div. Simple set `flex-grow: 1` to the long item.

```css
.subscribe-background-div h2 {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

**DEMO**

https://codepen.io/blackcityhenry/pen/vYRRWYw

Comment: Added the flex-grow but still doesn't work lol. I've experimented stuff and the only thing that works is If I put the margin-left to 67%, but when I do that, It pushes the email text to the left

Answer (score 1):

```css
body {
  background-color: #000000;
}

.subscribe-background-div {
  width: 339px;
  height: 48px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid #FFFFFFD9;
  border-radius: 12px;
  opacity: 1;
  margin-top: 5%;
  background-color: transparent;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.subscribe-background-div h2 {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 0px;
  color: #717179;
  opacity: 1;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.subscribe-btn {
  width: 40%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 0;
  border: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class='subscribe-background-div'>
  <h2>Email Address</h2>
  <Button class="btn btn-light me-5 subscribe-btn">Subscribe</Button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this works for you.

[image]

```
.subscribe-btn {
    width: 126px;
    height: 48px;
    border-top-right-radius: 12px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 12px;
}
.subscribe-background-div h2 {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    color: #717179;
    opacity: 1;
    /* margin-top: 45px; */
    margin-left: 20px;
}
.subscribe-background-div {
    width: 339px;
    height: 48px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    opacity: 1;
    border: 1px solid #FFFFFFD9;
    border-radius: 12px;
    opacity: 1;
    margin-top: 5%;
    background: #000;
    align-content: center;
}
<div className='subscribe-background-div'>
  <h2>Email Address</h2>
  <button className="btn btn-light me-5 subscribe-btn">
Subscribe
</button>
</div>
```